# Get keys from map in scala

Tags: scala

I have a problem with this code, the compiler tells me of an error in

`for (key <- keys) type mismatch, found: Unit, required: Seq[String]`.

I'm getting the map keys in the wrong way? Thanks

```
def sorted(): Seq[String] = {
var sorting: Seq[String] = Seq()
var keys = db.keys.toSeq.sortWith(_ < _)
for (key <- keys) {
  var names = db(key).sortWith(_ < _)
  for (name <- names) {
    sorting = sorting :+ name
  }
}
```

}

Comment: You are not returning anything. You can add a final line like `sorting` to return that. - BTW, your code abuse too much of mutability, can you explain your goal and provide some **MCVE**, I believe there are easier and safer ways of doing that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think doing this the functional way you can simplify this a lot:

```
def sorted(): Seq[String] =
  for{
    key <- db.keys.toSeq.sorted
    value <- db(key).sorted
  } yield value
```

1. Get the Keys in a sorted `Seq`.
2. Get the Values in a sorted `Seq`.

As with a `for-comprehension` this will `flatMap` these `Seqs`.

The result for: `val db = Map("one" -> Seq("eins", "uno"), "two" -> Seq("zwei", "due"))`

is: `Vector(eins, uno, due, zwei)`

Let me know if you don't understand something.

Answer (score 2):

Your code implies you have a `Map[String, Seq[String]]`
So I would one-liner it:

```
db.keys.toSeq.sorted.flatMap(db(_).sorted)
```

(just add `.toSeq` if values are not already a `Seq`)

Answer (score 0):

I guess `db` has type `Map[String, Seq[String]]`.

<strike>I guess `db` has type `Map[String, String]`.</strike>

Then firstly here

```
sorting = sorting :+ name
```

you try to concatenate `sorting` of type `Seq[String]` and `name` of type `Char`. What do you mean? Try `sorting :+ name.toString`.

Secondly `for` returns `Unit` and you promise that `sorted()` returns `Seq[String]`. It's `for-yield` that returns something. Maybe you want to return the final value of `var sorting`. Then you should do this explicitly. In Scala the last line is what method returns.

Try

```
def sorted(): Seq[String] = {
  var sorting: Seq[String] = Seq()
  var keys = db.keys.toSeq.sortWith(_ < _)
  for (key <- keys) {
    var names = db(key).sortWith(_ < _)
    for (name <- names) {
      sorting = sorting :+ name
    }
  }
  sorting
}
```

Comment: I think you mean `Map[String, Seq[String]]`

Comment: @pme Maybe you're right. This makes more sense. Thanks.